# Netbeans Module not being deployed

Tags: javascript, ajax, netbeans

**Original Question Title:**

*C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\ConsultingAgency\nbproject\build-impl.xml:563: The module has not been deployed.*

---

hello

I am new to javaserver face developing and following some netbean tutorials on this

Generating a JavaServer Faces CRUD Application from a Database :
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf-jpa-crud-wizard.html

when I run this generated code on my computer I get this message and it doesn't seem to work.

C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\ConsultingAgency\nbproject\build-impl.xml:563: The module has not been deployed.

Can anyone help me solving this problem ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found out what the problem is, at least mind is, when you deploy an enterprise app client, which references an EJB project, it defaults to include the EJB jar in your app client jar, so when you deploy your app client, glassfish sees 2 types of jars, and got confused about which type of module you are trying to deploy. So I went to the app client library option, unchecked the package option, and it deployed my app client.

However, now it's complaining about my app client deployment jar cannot find the the ejb class files: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

I think this only happens when you use @EJB injection, but if you use jndi lookup it should be fine.